# правильные параметры на ось Х

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, matplotlib

наш стенд в лаборатории выдает такой лог:

```
1533288841;34441818;03-08-2018;09:34:01;.tmp9;36.748970;
1533288842;34442968;03-08-2018;09:34:02;.tmp9;36.748970;
1533288844;34444019;03-08-2018;09:34:04;.tmp9;36.748970;
1533288845;34445029;03-08-2018;09:34:05;.tmp9;36.748970;
1533288846;34446025;03-08-2018;09:34:06;.tmp9;36.748970;
1533288847;34447064;03-08-2018;09:34:07;.tmp9;36.748970;
1533288848;34448072;03-08-2018;09:34:08;.tmp9;36.748970;
1533288849;34449120;03-08-2018;09:34:09;.tmp9;36.748970;
1533288850;34450143;03-08-2018;09:34:10;.tmp9;36.773521;
```

Пытаемся построить график температуры по времени.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (10, 5)
fn = r'C:\\NET\\Log\\tmp92.trd'

df = pd.read_csv(fn, sep=';')
df.columns = ['atime', 'ctime', 'date', 'time', 'tag' , 'tmp' , 'NaN']
df['date'] = df.date.astype('datetime64[ns]')
df['time'] = df.time.astype('datetime64[ns]')
df.dropna(axis = 1, thresh=3)
df.drop(df.columns[[0, 1, 4]], axis=1, inplace=True)

plt.xlabel('Время')
plt.ylabel('Температура (С)')
plt.title('Температура на выходе активатора')
plt.grid(True)
df.plot(x='time', y='tmp')
plt.show()
```

Вроде получилось, но не можем победить нижнюю ось.
хотелось видеть там время, а не 08-06-10
понятно что косяк в формате дата+время. - как сделать только время??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно Pandas отлично спраляется с данной задачей если у столбца правильный тип данных - `datetime`.

Пример:

```
In [73]: df['Время'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + ' ' + df['time'])

In [74]: df
Out[74]:
        atime     ctime        date      time    tag        tmp  NaN               Время
0  1533288841  34441818  03-08-2018  09:34:01  .tmp9  36.748970  NaN 2018-03-08 09:34:01
1  1533288842  34442968  03-08-2018  09:34:02  .tmp9  36.748970  NaN 2018-03-08 09:34:02
2  1533288844  34444019  03-08-2018  09:34:04  .tmp9  36.748970  NaN 2018-03-08 09:34:04
3  1533288845  34445029  03-08-2018  09:34:05  .tmp9  36.748970  NaN 2018-03-08 09:34:05
4  1533288846  34446025  03-08-2018  09:34:06  .tmp9  36.748970  NaN 2018-03-08 09:34:06
5  1533288847  34447064  03-08-2018  09:34:07  .tmp9  36.748970  NaN 2018-03-08 09:34:07
6  1533288848  34448072  03-08-2018  09:34:08  .tmp9  36.748970  NaN 2018-03-08 09:34:08
7  1533288849  34449120  03-08-2018  09:34:09  .tmp9  36.748970  NaN 2018-03-08 09:34:09
8  1533288850  34450143  03-08-2018  09:34:10  .tmp9  36.773521  NaN 2018-03-08 09:34:10

In [75]: df.dtypes
Out[75]:
atime             int64
ctime             int64
date             object
time             object
tag              object
tmp             float64
NaN             float64
Время    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object

In [76]: df.plot(x='Время', y='tmp')
Out[76]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x1b914930470>
```

---

**UPDATE:** matplotlib позволяет контролировать формат подписей:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\download\tmp92.trd', sep=';', 
                 header=None, names=['date','time','tmp'], 
                 usecols=[2,3,5])
df['Время'] = pd.to_datetime(df.pop('date') + ' ' + df.pop('time'))

ax = df.plot(x='Время', y='tmp')

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M\n%d.%m.%Y'))
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: посмотрите пожалуйста на картинки 
https://ibb.co/e7DnGK
подпись под Х у нас не время, а какая-то помесь из дня месяца и часа

Comment: Вобщем мы поняли почему у вас все хорошо а у нас плохо :)
Вы обрабатываете 9 записей, а у нас 17369 rows.
Если растянуть наш график в ширину - то время появится в нормальном виде...
вот попробуйте с нашим файлом - как у вас ось Х будет выглядеть
https://dropmefiles.com/PwmxF

Comment: и еще вопрос - дату в наш вид не вернуть ? будет 2018-03-08 ?

Comment: @Ivan, вы можете выложить весь ваш датасет на какой-нибудь файлообменник, чтобы можно было воспроизвести график?

Comment: в комментарии выше я ссылку кидал.
https://dropmefiles.com/PwmxF

Comment: @Ivan, а в каком формате вы хотите получить подписи по оси X? А если у вас будут значения принадлежащие нескольким дням - как быть тогда?

Comment: планируется график по дням. хотим просто часы и минуты. хотяб часы если много значений. но ни как не то что мы имеем :(  какую-то фигню 
08-08 12 = два куска даты и кусок часы

Comment: @Ivan, добавил вариант с форматированием подписей. Похоже на русскоязычном SO сломался сервис добавления картинок - чтобы прсмотреть на результат кликните по ссылке в конце ответа...

Comment: Супер !!!
А как еще графиков можно добавить на одном экране.
У нас этих температур штук 10 и давления 3.
Как быть с делениями по оси Y - если одновременно и давление и температуру выводить ? А еще ток мотора есть и обороты :(

Comment: @Ivan, лучше задать отдельный вопрос и привести в нем пример данных...

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/865824/%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b8-y-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81311/discussion-between-maxu-and-ivan).

Comment: @Ivan, ответить смогу не раньше вечера (по португальскому времени) ;)

Answer (score 3):

Если Вам нужно только время, то можно воспользоваться методом [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html#).

Я немного изменил Ваш скрипт, чтобы получить нужный график:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (10, 5)
fn = 'pydata.txt'

df = pd.read_csv(fn, sep=';')
df.columns = ['atime', 'ctime', 'date', 'time', 'tag' , 'tmp' , 'NaN']

df.dropna(axis = 1, thresh=3)
df.drop(df.columns[[0, 1, 4]], axis=1, inplace=True)

plt.xlabel('Время')
plt.ylabel('Температура (С)')
plt.title('Температура на выходе активатора')
plt.grid(True)

# Здесь в качестве x передаем преобразованный в тип datetime столбец
plt.plot(pd.to_datetime(df['time']), df['tmp'])

plt.show()
```

Получился вот такой график:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо добрый человек. Весь день мозг с datetime ломали :)
у нас не получалось время выцепить

Comment: @Ivan Если ответ решил Вашу проблему, пожалуйста отметьте его как правильный.

Кстати, для оформления подписей осей можно использовать синтаксис latex - например, градусы Цельсия можно указать так: `plt.ylabel('Температура $^\circ С$')`

Comment: блин, не можем повторить код :) у нас все так же кажет ось X. а про формат Цельсия ругается на /

Comment: https://ibb.co/e7DnGK - вот картинка. Цельсий победили.

Comment: а вот дата и время = object, а не дата  и во второй колонке время
df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 17369 entries, 0 to 17368
Data columns (total 4 columns):
date    17369 non-null object
time    17369 non-null object
tmp     17369 non-null float64
NaN     0 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(2), object(2)
memory usage: 542.9+ KB

Comment: может у нас настройки питона неправильные - но всеравно дата+тиме кругом. нет просто времени.
https://ibb.co/kCCpDz
https://ibb.co/e13J6K