# Как отобразить несколько графиков с разными параметрами на оси Y на одном "листе" в matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, python-3.6

Имеем лабораторный стенд. Снимаем в папочку логи с датчиков температуры, давления, оборотов двигателя, ток двигателя.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (10, 5)
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\net\log\tmp92.trd', sep=';', 
                 header=None, names=['date','time','tmp'], 
                 usecols=[2,3,5])
df['Время'] = pd.to_datetime(df.pop('date') + ' ' + df.pop('time'))

plt.xlabel('Время')
plt.ylabel('Температура (С)')
plt.title('Температура на выходе активатора')
plt.grid(True)
ax = df.plot(x='Время', y='tmp')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M\n%d.%m.%Y'))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

По одному строить графики вроде научились. А как бы сводный получить за день работы? Чтобы одновременно видно было давления, температуры, обороты и ток - за синхронизированные по оси времени X.

Пример данных по [ссылке](https://dropmefiles.com/rHbHd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтобы отобразить более двух категорий величин можно воспользоваться `subplots`:

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

plt.style.use('ggplot')


p = Path(r'C:\download\data\SO\865824')

df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, sep=';', header=None, usecols=[2,3,5],
                            names=['date','time',f.stem], index_col=['date','time'])
               for f in p.glob('*.trd')],
               axis=1)

df = df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df.index.get_level_values(0) + ' ' + df.index.get_level_values(1)))


fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(16, 8));

df.filter(regex=r'^tmp').plot(ax=axes[0])
# дополнительная ось со значениями давления на оси Y справа
ax_press = df.filter(regex=r'^press').plot(ax=axes[0], secondary_y=True)
df.filter(regex=r'^tok').plot(ax=axes[1], sharex=True)

axes[1].xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M\n%d.%m.%Y'))

axes[0].set_ylabel('Температура')
ax_press.set_ylabel('Давление')
axes[1].set_ylabel('Ток мотора')
axes[1].set_xlabel('Время')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но лучше отображать каждую категорию на отдельном "под-графике":

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 1, figsize=(16, 8));

df.filter(regex=r'^tmp').plot(ax=axes[0])
df.filter(regex=r'^press').plot(ax=axes[1], sharex=True)
df.filter(regex=r'^tok').plot(ax=axes[2], sharex=True)

axes[-1].xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M\n%d.%m.%Y'))

axes[0].set_ylabel('Температура')
axes[1].set_ylabel('Давление')
axes[2].set_ylabel('Ток мотора')
axes[-1].set_xlabel('Время')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: MaxU - сломали голову - как все легенды в лево-верх прижать на всех графиках ?
plt.legend(loc = 'upper left') - действует только на последний :( - где ток

Comment: @Ivan, я думаю стоит задать отдельный SO вопрос ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

plt.style.use('ggplot')


p = Path(r'C:\download\data\SO\865824')

df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, sep=';', header=None, usecols=[2,3,5],
                            names=['date','time',f.stem], index_col=['date','time'])
               for f in p.glob('*.trd')],
               axis=1)

df = df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df.index.get_level_values(0) + ' ' + df.index.get_level_values(1)))

ax = df.filter(regex=r'^tmp').plot(figsize=(16, 10))

df.filter(regex=r'^press').plot(ax=ax, secondary_y=True)

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M\n%d.%m.%Y'))
```

результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PS я специально переименовал файл `tmp32.trd` в `tmp32.trd.1`, чтобы значения `tmp32`не отображались на графике. В этом файле значения на много порядков больше остальных - в результате все остальные значения температуры будут выглядеть как прямые на общем графике.

Comment: а можно еще как-то примотать график тока и оборотов?. ниже я так понимаю - чтоб по времени синхронизировать. Ещеб в какой нить хпмл сохранить чтоб распечатать можно было